# Count Number of Columns In Hive

Tags: sql, sql-server, count, hive, distinct

I am looking for a way to count the number of columns in a table in Hive.

I know the following code works in Microsoft SQL Server. Is there a Hive equivalent?

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_CATALOG = 'database_name'
   AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'schema_name'
   AND TABLE_NAME = 'table_name'
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this

```
SHOW COLUMNS (FROM|IN) table_name [(FROM|IN) db_name]
```

Comment: At the end of the SHOW COLUMNS command, it shows the number of rows returned, which indicates the number of columns, so this answer is correct.

Comment: Even 'Describe db_name.table_name;' will give the count in similar way.

Answer (score 5):

Try this, it will show you the columns of your table:

```
DESCRIBE schemaName.tableName;
```

Comment: but not the count

Answer (score 1):

I do not know of a way to count the columns directly, however, I solved the problem for my needs indirectly via:

```
echo 'table1name:, '`hive -e 'describe schemaname.table1name;' | grep -v 'col_name' | wc -l > num_columns.csv
echo 'table2name:, '`hive -e 'describe schemaname.table2name;' | grep -v 'col_name' | wc -l >> num_columns.csv
...
```

(I needed the `grep -v` bit because I have headers on by default; without it you get one too many lines counted in the `wc -l` step.)

Answer (score 0):

you have to check if your HIVE include HIVE-287 because for versions of HIVE which don't include HIVE-287, you'll need to use COUNT(1) in place of COUNT(*).

Comment: Thank you for your response! Are you saying that columns are counted with COUNT(1) in Hive? What would be the rest of the code? The above code doesn't work.

Comment: I'm saying that you need use COUNT(1) if your HIVE version don't include HIVE-287. Then you have to download this the patch from https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-287.
if you don't want to download the patch or you have HIVE-287 and the code doesn't work, use something like this:
SELECT col1, col2, count(1) FROM table GROUP BY col1, col2

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but your suggestions output the number of rows in my table. I'm trying to find the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Just do a describe it will show you all columns then at the bottom then you can see number of rows it fetched that is number of columns.